# What is another way to say the need for?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What is another way to say "the need for" in regards to mental health system reform

Comment: Needs more context

Comment: Agreed, this needs more context. But you might try using "is necessary", as in, "mental health system reform is necessary."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Exigent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exigent): (Formal) Pressing; demanding.

- An exigent need exists for mental health reform.

[Apodictic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apodictic): (Formal) Clearly established or beyond dispute.

- There is an apodictic need for mental health reform.

[Supererogation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supererogation): (Formal) Do more than necessary. (Synonym: [operose](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/operose).)

- Mental health suffers from unnecessary supererogation, reform should be considered.

[Mutatis mutandis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis): (Adverb) Mutatis mutandis is a Latin phrase meaning "changing [only] those things which need to be changed" or more simply "[only] the necessary changes having been made".

This usage should be used as a justification.

- Healthcare in America is dire need of reform, mutatis mutandis, especially for mental health.

[Ad verecundiam](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad_verecundiam): Appeal to authority, argument from authority or **authoritative argument**.

- The need for mental health reform is indisputable ad verecundiam.

---

It is probably worth noting that most of these words/phrases are very uncommon/rarely used so take care if you do decide to use one (and to be considered outside of the suggestions of @Jeroen)

Answer (score 0):

- *necessity* — quite formal
- *urgency* — quite formal
- *requirement* — ordinary
- *obligation* — quite formal
- *prerequisite* — formal

Answer (score 0):

Make it an active verb. That often does the trick:
The mental health system urgently needs reforming.